CDK ComponentPortal how to remove Component from view
I'm new to CDK overlays/portals. I have created a component based on the example code from CDK docs. I have removed the example code for both templatePortal and domPortal, in order to concentrate on the componentPortal. I am now trying to figure how to remove the component that gets created in the overlay. Here is a Stackblitz link. I have scoured the internet and the online docs, but haven't found a solution or example of this programmatic removal (only examples clicking on the overlay).
In the "parent" I have a button calling a method to attempt removal or destruction of the created child:
<button (click)="destroyRef()" style="background-color: orange">DESTROY</button>

In the parent, I am trying things like this:
export class CdkPortalOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  private parentElement: HTMLElement;
  componentPortal: ComponentPortal<ComponentPortalExample> =
    new ComponentPortal(ComponentPortalExample);
  overlayRef: OverlayRef;
  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parentElement = document.getElementById('parentId')!;
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create();
    // this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(this.getOverlayConfig());
    this.componentRef = this.overlayRef.attach(this.componentPortal);
    const element = this.componentRef.location.nativeElement;
  }

  destroyRef() {
    // PROBLEM 1: these lines are not causing the component to be destroyed.
    this.overlayRef.detach();
    this.componentRef.destroy();
    // this.cdr.markForCheck();
    console.log('destroy() called');
  }
  

Here is the "child" component that gets created:
@Component({
  selector: 'component-portal-example',
  template: `
  <button (click)="youClickedMe('HELLO WORLD')">
  CLICK ME
</button>

  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ComponentPortalExample {

  youClickedMe(event: any) {
    console.log('You clicked me', event);
    this.optionSelected.emit('YOU CLICKER!');
  }
}

NOTE - in my example, I am getting two instantiations for some reason. The one in the top left corner is the one in the div.cdk-overlay. I don't understand why the created child appears in two places. But, that is not happening in the app on my computer, so it is not my primary concern. However, if you also understand that, feel free to point out that solution, too.
THANKS.

Are you trying to add the component to the overlay or to the the div with the component portal? You are getting two component-portal-example bc one is added to the overlay and another to the portal (This creates one component: new ComponentPortal(ComponentPortalExample) and cdkPortalOutlet directive, this does display the second one:   this.overlayRef.attach(this.componentPortal))

if you dont intend to add it to the overlay ref, just inject the cdkPortalOutlet @ViewChild(CdkPortalOutlet, { read: CdkPortalOutlet })   host: CdkPortalOutlet; in your component, and call this.host.detach();. Remove. this.overlayRef.attach(this.componentPortal) to dont display twice the component at the top.

@OscarLudick in my real-world case, I think I need it in the overaly, as it is for a select component options panel that needs to be above every other component and not be constrained by the height of the parent or grandparent.

Then your example is ok, just delete <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="componentPortal"></ng-template> and eveything should work as expected. https://stackblitz.com/edit/usxnjp-4rlj7g

@OscarLudick That does fix it! Thanks! If you want to set this as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

See that you are using document.getElementById('parentId') but you have a template reference variable
//your code
<div class="example-portal-outlet" #parentId>
  
</div>

//should be
<div class="example-portal-outlet" id="parentId">
  
</div>

See also you use a <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="componentPortal"></ng-template> if you want to attach manually you needn't
Your forked stackblitz
